# Difference between TabBar and TabBarItem within a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

A custom subclass of `UITabBarController` will have a `tabBar` property and a `tabBarItem` property (of type *UITabBarItem!*).

Since subclasses of `UITabBarController` come with a built-in `tabBar` I am wondering what the use case of `tabBarItem` would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has `tabBarItem` because it inherits from `UIViewController`. That property is for representing the corresponding view controller when within a `UITabBarController`. Since a `UITabBarController` is not usually inside another `UITabBarController`, that property doesn't have much use. Summarizing, only care about `tabBarItem` when you're dealing with tabbed view controllers, not the tab controller itself.

Comment: Ah, that must be it. `UINavigationController` inherits from `UIViewController` and so the `taBarItem` property is available as a result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController` is subclass of `UIViewController` so it inherit `tabBarItem` property

Documentation:

> **tabBarItem**
>   The tab bar item that represents the view controller when added to a tab bar controller.

But since `UITabBarController` cannot be added to another `UITabBarController` this property basically useless.